# When to link tables or keep it as one table with more fields

Tags: sql

I have a table with lots of fields which holds "totals" like so:

```
UserID | total_classA | total_classB | total_classC   // and so on
```

I could have a second table however with:

```
ClassType | Total | UserID
```

But I don't really see how a second table would be beneficial here for a many to one relationship, firstly i would have to store more rows of data, AND i have to use a join for selecting data.

But alot of things i read would suggest having two tables is best over one table with lots of fields... why is this as i do not see the advantage to that in the above situation =/

Comment: Well, do you need to be able to add a `total_classD` in the future? Does `classA`, `classB`, or `classC` have a semantic meaning elsewhere in the database?

Comment: They have no meaning else where no and yeh there will be alot more classes in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your data cleanly, as you propose with your 'second table'.

You can always get the summarized column total display with a PIVOT (depending on your platform) or a specialized query if and when you need it.

The biggest benefit of doing so will be the elimination of having to change your table structure with every additional class type you decide to introduce.  You will be able to extend your data tracking capabilities simply by adding rows (DML rather than DDL).

Take a look at [second normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form) for more of a technical explanation for going this route.

Comment: So its more down to the convenience of design over the performance gains?

Comment: I would ask you to show metrics around your supposed "performance gains".  Blocking contention on updating a single record by multiple requests will often slow things down over updating more granular data with less contention.